# With Horizontal ScrollView, Displaying a text file which divided to pages

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am new for Android.
I want to display a text file with Horizontal ScrollView.
But I can not split to pages. Just long sentences I have.
The text will be like a bookreader.
How can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library, if you want to do a reader

https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android